# How to convert 2D character array into image in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, reinforcement-learning

I was just training a reinforcement learning agent to beat my own roguelike game, thing is I used to train him by labelling the map and feeding it into a multi-layer perceptron.

The map consists of a 2D array of characters (eg: 'z' is zombie) and I was wondering if it were possible to convert the array into a grayscale png of itself so I can use a convolutional neural network. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: image uses numbers to describe colors - so if you will have i.e. `0` instead of `"z"` and `255` instead other chars then you will have array with image which you could save in file using `cv2.imwrite()`. Eventually you may need tuples `(0,0,0)` and `(255,255,255)` to have file `(R,G,B)`

Comment: @furas Sorry for my low description, I meant that it is a 2D array that I would like to display as text. The 2D array is composed of characters that I want to be made simply into an image showing the characters written out over a black background :)

Comment: this makes problem. You can use `pillow` or `cv` to work with image and they have function to add text on image. But first you have to know how many pixels will use char on image and then you have to calculate size of image. For `monospace` fonts all chars will have the same size (in pixels) but for other fonts char `w` may use more space then char `i`.